# Swift: How can I update NSMenuItem while it is active (visible)?

Tags: swift, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nsevent

I created a simple timer which updates a counter within a NSMenuItem.

```
func timerUpdate(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

        // calculating time
        let timeLeft = self.lxTimeLeft() // returns a double of remaining seconds
        let hoursLeft = Int(timeLeft/3600)
        let minLeft = Int(timeLeft/60) - (hoursLeft*60)
        let secLeft = Int(timeLeft) - (hoursLeft*3600) - (minLeft*60)

        let hoursLeftStr = String(format:"%02d", hoursLeft)
        let minLeftStr = String(format:"%02d", minLeft)
        let secLeftStr = String(format:"%02d", secLeft)

        println("timeLeft \(hoursLeftStr):\(minLeftStr):\(secLeftStr)")
        self.menuActiveFor.title = "\(self.activatedFor) \(hoursLeftStr):\(minLeftStr):\(secLeftStr)h"

        self.statusMenu.update() // not working
    }
}
```

Basically it works, but when I open the NSMenu it won't refresh the NSMenuItem (UI). I found a solution for Objective-C ([How to update NSMenu while it's open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136692/how-to-update-nsmenu-while-its-open)) but sadly, I am not able to adapt this using Swift.

Comment: Use Runloop or Dispatch https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/213

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the docu about `NSRunLoop` when your menu is displayed none of your threads will get control. You need to tell the OS you want to participate.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(yourTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)` solved my problem.